# Employee Hierarchy in Oracle with missing relationship

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on one Oracle query which has below data:

```
Emp Designation reporter
A   Director    
B   Manager     A
C   Supervisor  B
F   Supervisor  A
G   Director    
H   Emp         B
P   Supervisor  B
Q   Manager     G
```

The hierarchy is : 
Director
Manager
Supervisor
Emp

In the above table, we have missing relationship. 
eg. In the 4th record, Manager is missing , 'F' (Supervisor) is directly reporting 'A' (director)
In the 6th record, Supervisor is missing, 'H'(Emp) is directly reporting to 'B' (Manager)
I am trying to build the oracle query to get below result:

```
Director    Manager Supervisor  Emp
A            B        C 
A                     F 
G            Q      
A            B                   H
             B        P 



select a.emp Director, b.emp Supervisor , c.emp manager, d.emp emp
from
hr_test a
left join hr_test b
on a.emp = b.reporter 
left join
hr_test c
on b.emp = c.reporter
left join
hr_test d
on c.emp = d.reporter
where a.DESIGNATION = 'Director'
```

But with the above query, I am not getting the missing relationship.

I will really appreciate if anyone help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes here. Why is there a need to downvote the question if the op has shown effort in writing a query? . Yes, the table designs could be bad . However it is not always the user's fault. isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e6a0a/12)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE hr_test ( Emp, Designation, reporter ) AS
SELECT 'A',   'Director',    NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',   'Manager',     'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',   'Supervisor',  'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'F',   'Supervisor',  'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'G',   'Director',    NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'H',   'Emp',         'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'P',   'Supervisor',  'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Q',   'Manager',     'G' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Director,
       Manager,
       Supervisor,
       Emp
FROM   (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( Emp ) AS root,
         Designation,
         Emp
  FROM   hr_test t
  START WITH emp NOT IN ( SELECT reporter FROM hr_test WHERE reporter IS NOT NULL )
  CONNECT BY PRIOR reporter = emp
)
PIVOT ( MAX( Emp ) FOR Designation IN (
    'Director'   AS DIRECTOR,
    'Manager'    AS MANAGER,
    'Supervisor' AS SUPERVISOR,
    'Emp'        AS EMP
  )
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e6a0a/12/0)**:

```
| DIRECTOR | MANAGER | SUPERVISOR |    EMP |
|----------|---------|------------|--------|
|        A |       B |     (null) |      H |
|        A |       B |          P | (null) |
|        G |       Q |     (null) | (null) |
|        A |       B |          C | (null) |
|        A |  (null) |          F | (null) |
```